# Webpack does not load/resolve dependencies of npm package included through git

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, webpack

I just got started with [`gulp-starter`](https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-starter). I'm including a private npm package (named "Pigeon") from a GIT repository and I'm having problems getting everything running smoothly. The installation of the package went fine, all the files are there in `node_modules`, including all of its dependencies.

**myApp/node_modules/pigeon/index.js:**

```
export MyModule from './my-module.js';
```

**myApp/src/app.js:**

```
import ClientPigeoneer from 'pigeon';
```

**Webpack loader:**

```
  var webpackConfig = {
    context: 'myApp/src/scripts',
    plugins: [],
    resolve: {
      root: 'myApp/src/scripts',
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: ["es2015", "stage-1"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Console output:**

```
ERROR in ./~/pigeon/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/mirague/Projects/myApp/node_modules/pigeon/index.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export MyModule from './my-module';
|
 @ ./src/scripts/app.js 9:14-31
```

How can I get Webpack to resolve this package? Do I need to add another loader?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code instead for your resolution:

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'myApp/src/scripts'],
    fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
},
```

That way webpack will know to look in your node modules directory for your installed modules.

Comment: It can find its way to all other dependencies already, and it seems to know where `pigeon` is located, as it tries to load the `index.js`. However, it does not know -how- to handle this file, for some reason... I tried your approach with identical results.

Comment: Perhaps it's because the `index.js` is using `es6` syntax and the `babel-loader` is told to exclude everything in `node_modules`.

Comment: mm that _may_ be. Try including the pigeon app. Although that is weird bc if you include it in your app it should go through the babel loader anyway.

Comment: When using a good old `module.exports` it seemed to resolve partially, now I am met with these warnings and errors: https://gist.github.com/mirague/f99c7c183860d5c6348c8a31c4d4ceaa